# Как переделать скрипт, чтобы выполнялись GPU вычисления вместо CPU вычислений?

Tags: python, cuda, gpu

## Ludmila - решение нерешенных математических задач методом подбора

### Описание

Скрипт Ludmila предназначен для решения нерешенных математических задач методом подбора.
Есть список элементов уравнений:

- числа (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)
- операции (+, *, /, -)
- скобки (левая, правая)
- степень (квадратная, кубическая, корень квадратный, корень кубический)
- x (может быть несколько в наборе - x0, x1, x2, ...)

Есть входящие наборы данных:

- data1.txt (линейное уравнение)
- data2.txt (теорема пифагора)
- data3.txt (ряд простых чисел)

Например набор data1.txt (линейное уравнение) выглядит вот так:

```
3235    51  62  73

3350    52  63  74

3467    53  64  75

... и т.д. (всего 100 элеметов в наборе)
```

Первая цифра значение y, последующие цифры значения x (в данном случае x0, x1, x2)

Для нахождения верного уравнения перебираются комбинации уравнений. Выглядит это примерно так:

```
y = 1

y = 2

...
```

перебираются все уравнения длинной 1, затем длинной 2. Уравнения длинной 3 могут выглядеть например так:

```
y = 1 + x0

y = 1 + x1
```

... и так далее, пока не дойдет до:

```
y = x0 * x1 + x2
```

В итоге набор данных (3235  51  62  73) выдаст совпадение, далее эта форумла перебирает все наборы данных data1.txt их всего 100 штук. И если все 100 наборы данных прошли проверку, то уравнение считается решенным.

### Оптимизация

Так как нет смысла уравнения в котором рядом стоят например два оператора +, поэтому есть правила конкатенации - что может стоять рядом друг с другом, а что нет. В результате чего скорость работы скрипта была увеличина в 15 раз. Правила конкатенации находятся в config.py, переменная types.

### Производительность

Производительность на CPU:

- Линейное уравнение решается за 7 секунд (5 символов) v|x0;o|*;v|x1;o|+;v|x2
- Теорема пифагора решается за 8100 секунд (8 символов) bl|(;v|x0;e|**2;o|+;v|x1;e|**2;br|);e|**0.5

### Задачи

Главной задачей данного скрипта является решение нерешенных математических задач

- [Открытые математические проблемы](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D1%82%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8B%D1%82%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8B)
- [Задачи тысячелетия](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B8_%D1%82%D1%8B%D1%81%D1%8F%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%8F)

Но не все они могут быть представлены в виде наборов данных.

### Запуск

- в файле config.py в переменной data_id указать id набора данных (1 - линейное, 2 - теорема пифагора, 3 - ряд простых чисел)
- запустить файл ludmila.py командой:
  c:\Python37\python e:\python\maths\ludmila.py
- результат будет в консоле, а так же в лог файле log.txt

### Вопросы

У меня есть два вопроса к сообществу:

- Есть ли подобные скрипты? Возможно кто-то уже делал такое и мой скрипт бессмысленный потому что эта работа уже проделана кем-то другим.
- Вопрос к тем кто работал с CUDA. Сейчас вычисления производятся на CPU. Возможно ли переделать на GPU тем самым повысив производительность в десятки раз?

### Ссылка на исходники

https://github.com/nevstas/ludmila

Comment: Такое ощущение, что в спам угодил :D Кст, в том репозитории у автора файл ludmila.py (и думаю все остальные) в кодировке cp1251, вместо utf-8, из-за чего и кракозябры в комментариях

Comment: Ну есть же SymPy: https://www.sympy.org/en/features.html который умеет с символами работать. Как-раз что-то такое.